# JSON doesn't pick the returned data and keep the page display loading image

Tags: javascript, json

I am using JSON to pass the data from web service to JavaScript.

It was working before but suddenly I can not go in to JavaScript side after retrieving data in web service.

It just display loading image

I have this

```
$.ajax({
  url: "webservices/ProdMonitorService.asmx/GetEstTimePrelimFinalCur12Month",
  data: "{'myactivity':'" + myactivity + "','myproddate':'" +   mynewprddatee     + "'}",
  dataType: "json",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  async: false,
  success: function (data) {
  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
```

instead of `success: function (data) {`  I also used

```
error: function (data) {
   alert("errors : " + data.ToString()); }
```

but it didn't stop there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `async: false,`?

Comment: the data option should be a JSON object not a String representing JSON...

Comment: ProTip: DO NOT manually create your own JSON, use `JSON.stringify(obj)`.

Comment: but why not just an actual JSON object @RocketHazmat?

Comment: @happytimeharry: Depends on what the server expects.  Maybe the server expects a JSON string in the POST body.  He's doing `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`, so as long as the server expects a JSON string as the body, it's fine.

Comment: ah thats news to me, thanks for the info @RocketHazmat!

Comment: Where do you display this "loading image"?  Do you see anything in the console and/or network traffic section of your debug tools?

Comment: same code wokrs for another part of the project. It was working but probably something got wrong in returned data  . I don't see the error message that's why I stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var data = {
    "myactivity": myactivity,
    "myproddate": mynewprddatee
};

$.ajax({
    url: "webservices/ProdMonitorService.asmx/GetEstTimePrelimFinalCur12Month",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        // data is a JSON object
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.warn(request, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

ajax data should be a JSON object not a string with json format